# Wrong behaviour of fill_between with set_xlim()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

With python matplotlip I try to create a filled area between a numpy vector and zero. This works well, however with the use of set_xlim() something weird happens, see pictures below.

So the workaround with the mask works for now, but am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug?

Right behavior (with mask):
[image: Right behaviour]

Wrong behavior (with set_xlim()):
[image: Wrong behaviour]

```
mask = arange(4000,4050)
# wrong
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.fill_between(t, Load, 0)
ax.set_xlim([4000,4050])
ax.set_ylim([0,4000])
# right
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.fill_between(t[mask], Load[mask], 0)
```

Comment: The issue is that in the bottom example the poly is getting clipped so the bottom is at 700 not 0.

Comment: I suspect that it is related to https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5948

Comment: Does the problem still persist? I can't seem to reproduce on matplotlib 1.5.0 with random points to plot.